# android ConstraintLayout height percentage 0.99

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

When  app:layout_constraintHeight_percent is 0.50 or 0.80 it works fine, but when I set it to 0.99 , the Button go very long and larger than 99% of screen ?

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/sos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mybtn1"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.99"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <Button
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mybtn1"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Button 1" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Button 2" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you want a ScrollView?

Comment: because I want a 99% button with another button at bottom of first button and  user scroll view to see second button

Comment: You want the first button to occupy the entire screen and when the user scrolls down the second button shows up?

Comment: Answer edited, You should really rephrase the question because is barely understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.91"
            android:text="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_one"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: This is the most suitable code (as per me) that I wrote as to fulfill your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the 99% `layout_constraintHeight_percent` but when the combined height of the two buttons exceeds the height the on-screen height of the `ScrollView`. It just happens that 99% triggers this wayward behavior on your emulator/device. If you make the second button much taller, you will see the same behavior with smaller percentages.

I have found these types of layouts  to be problematic where a child's measurements depend upon the size of the parent and the parent size depends upon the size of the child. In your layout, the child `mybtn1` depends upon the parent `ConstraintLayout` (`app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.99"`) while the parent `ConstraintLayout` depends upon the size of the child `mybtn1` (`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`). This seems to work OK when the combined heights of the two buttons do not exceed the on-screen height of the `ScrollView` but fails miserably when the combined heights do exceed it. *(Setting `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `ScrollView` when the combined heights are less than the `ScrollView` height may work because there is an implicit fixed height to the `ScrollView` which is just the available real estate on the screen. This is just conjecture, though.)*

You can fix this with a little coding as follows:

Add an id to the `ScrollView`:

```
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
```

Place the following code in `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ScrollView scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Button button = findViewById(R.id.mybtn1);
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();

            // Get percentage height of button.
            float percent = lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight;

            // Explicitly set the button height based upon the ScrollView height.
            button.setHeight((int) (scrollView.getHeight() * percent));

            // Reset the percent height so it no longer has any effect.
            lp.matchConstraintPercentHeight = 1.0f;
        }
    });
}
```

This code will force a size on `mybtn1` that is 99% of the `ScrollView` height or whatever percentage is specified for the button.