# Android ScrollView - first view fill the entire screen

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I want to the first view fill the entire screen and when the user scrolls down the second view shows up but the `ScrollView` will not work!
I tried it with `ConstraintLayout` ([this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482381/android-constraintlayout-height-percentage-0-99/52482535)), but it still does not work!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="1" />    
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="2" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595063/android-horizontal-scrollview-behave-like-iphone-paging

Answer (score 0):

assume your first RelativeLayout in your scrollview is "view1". you should write a code like below example:

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
val displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels

view1.layoutParams.height = displayHeight
```